# Setting an application on start-up not working

Tags: c#, startup, windows

I'm developing an windows application and i want to set this application as windows start-up application for that i use this code:-

### Code

```
    public static void SetStartup(string AppName,
        bool enable)
    {
        try
        {
            string runKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey);
            if (enable)
            {
                if (startupKey.GetValue(AppName) == null)
                {
                    startupKey.Close();
                    startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
                    startupKey.SetValue(AppName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + " /StartMinimized");
                    startupKey.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
                startupKey.DeleteValue(AppName, false);
                startupKey.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

### Calling code on application load

```
SetStartup(Application.ExecutablePath, true);
```

And this code works fine.It sets application as a start-up application.
I check that executing msconfig command in run window.It shows this application checked in start-up tab.But when i restarts the system it doesn't start application.
Can any one tell me what is the problem and how can i solve that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got a answer for this problem.Use StreamWriter for creating a URL link of application instead of creating a LNK into start-up folder.

### Create shortcut

```
    private void appShortcutToStartup()
    {
        string linkName ="MytestLink";
        string startDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(startDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(startDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
            {
                string app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
                writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + app);
                writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
                string icon = Application.StartupPath + "\\backup (3).ico";
                writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

### Delete Shortcut

```
    private void delappShortcutFromStartup()
    {
        string linkName ="MytestLink";
        string startDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(startDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(startDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url");
        }
    }
```

This code works very fine.

Comment: I used above code with my windows application, its working fine with windows 10 but not with windows 7. any solution?

Comment: It is a well tested code on `Windows-7` working fine. Did you get the shortcut in startup folder?

Comment: Yes , Now Its working fine my problem solved. but it ask for UAC prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If everything points to it being in startup then I can only assume that that part of it is correct, but the application is failing to start for some reason.

When you start an application on run, it's working directory is set to C:\Windows\System32

I have had issues with applications that may be looking for files in its home directory such as config files but are unable to find them.

Normally files referenced the normal way will be found anyway, but if you are manually specifying a path in your code you can use:

```
string pathToDLL = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "LibraryFile.dll");
```

Using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory should give the path of the your application exe, rather than the working directory.

Could this be the cause of the problem?

Also, I'm going to assume Vista upwards is the OS, and if that's the case then your application would have to be running as elevated to write to that registry. So, if UAC is off and the machine is restarted then your application, if it's set in the manifest to run as requireAdministrator, would fail silently.

Martyn

Comment: Ok when we start an application on run, it's working directory is set to C:\Windows\System32.In my application i used some dll as reference.
In that case how can i run my application on system start up.

Comment: Edited to include path to DLL, hope that helps.

Comment: Finally i got a solution for this problem.I use StreamWriter for creating an URL link instead of creating lnk into start up folder.And it works.I'll post a full answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most simplest way would be by following the below steps

1.) Build your application

2.) Navigate to your debug folder

3) Copy the exe  and place it at your Startup location

```
**C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu\Programs\Startup**

            OR
```

Simply drag your exe over start menu--> Program-->Startup and Paste it there (i.e
   releasing the mouse button)

I guess that would do your work

Hope it helps